# Getting null on TimeType in Symfony2 Forms

Tags: php, symfony

i got weird error that when i submit my form with time type i got null values.

This is my FormType class:

```
class DailyTimeRecordType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('clockIn', 'time', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',     
            ),
            'input' => 'timestamp',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
        ))
        ->add('clockOut', 'time', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
        ))
        ->add('memo', 'textarea', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Memo details...',     
            ),
        ));         
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\DailyTimeRecord',
         'validation_groups' => array('DTR'),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_dailytimerecord';
    }
}
```

However when I set clockIn to DateTime i got values on submission, why is that so?

What I inputted are values like this: 10:30 AM, 12:00 AM etc.

Thanks!

Comment: null in post or database??

Comment: on the controller layer, when i var_dump $entity->getClockIn() i got null values. Thus throwing me validation errors telling me that it is not a valid value.

Comment: How did you define the type of `$clockIn` in the `DailyTimeRecord` entity?

Comment: /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="clock_in", type="time")
     */
    private $clockIn;